# How to translating C++/CX create_task with cancellation to equivalent C++/WinRT code?

Tags: c++-cx, c++-winrt

How does one get the cancellation token source to replace the create_task C++/CX call below with equivalent C++/WinRT code?

```
void MainPage::OnButtonClick(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ args)
{
    MessageDialog^ msgdlg = ref new MessageDialog("Choose a color", "How To Cancel Async");
    msgdlg->Commands->Append(ref new UICommand("Red", nullptr, Colors::Red));
    //...

    // Show the MessageDialog
    cancellationTokenSource = cancellation_token_source();
    task<IUICommand^> showTask = create_task(msgdlg->ShowAsync(),
        cancellationTokenSource.get_token());
    showTask.then([this, timer](task<IUICommand^> thisTask)
    {
        //...
    });
}

void MainPage::OnTimerTick(Object^ sender, Object^ args)
{
    cancellationTokenSource.cancel();
}
```

Comment: What is the language `C++/CX`?  Are you talking about "C++-CLI"?  The code you posted looks a lot like C# and not C++.  For example, `Object^` is not valid syntax for standard C++.  Neither is `ref new`.

Comment: Also, what is the language `C++/WinRT`?  What's with the syntax `[this, timer]`?  Doesn't look valid for standard C++.

Comment: If you are developing a GUI, I highly recommend using a framework other than MFC or raw Windows API.  There are many available, see [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: C++/CX is Microsoft C++ with Component Extensions based on COM, introduced along with Windows 8 which is very similar in appearance to C++/CLI. I am attempting to translate the C++/CX code above to C++17 compliant C++/WinRT.

Comment: @tho `[this, timer]` is the capture clause of a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Standard C++ since C++11. [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) is a language projection for the Windows Runtime, written in Standard C++. [C++/CX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/visual-c-language-reference-c-cx) is a language projection for the Windows Runtime using a non-standard extension to C++. Unlike C++/CLI, it compiles to native, unmanaged code.

Comment: [Canceling an asynchronous operation, and cancellation callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#canceling-an-asynchronous-operation-and-cancellation-callbacks) explains how to use a cancellation source with C++/WinRT.

Comment: Also look at Raymond Chen's blog posts [part 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200722-00/?p=103997) and [part 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200723-00/?p=104000/); part 2 in particular seems to have an almost direct translation for your code.

Comment: The two links (Docs, Raymond Chen's blog posts) discuss cancellation_token but do not mention cancellation_token_source.

Comment: "The co_await get_cancellation_token() produces a cancellation token for the current coroutine" - Raymond Chen blog mentioned how to cancel operation. Remember one of many different things between C++/CX and C++/WinRT: C++/CX is using PPL (Parallel Patterns Library) and C++/WinRT is using coroutines instead that. From Kenny Kerr: "Please don’t use PPL. PPL itself doesn’t work well and our C++/WinRT adapters for PPL have a few drawbacks." - https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/54#issuecomment-267388677

Comment: A C++/WinRT version of the (Windows Universal Sample) MessageDialog sample on Github will help in due course.